# git required password on every push

Tags: git

We have a git server in our company. I am using git GUI to connect to it and push and pull source codes to it. The problem is that every time that I want to push my files, I need to enter the password. Is there any way that I can setup the git gui in a way that it doesn't ask me to enter a password every time that I am pushing my files into server?

Comment: You should be able to use certificates for authentication instead of username/password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to setup you ssh keys. And the private key should either have empty passphrase or you install an agent so that you don't have to type in the password.

See if this link helps: http://progit.org/book/ch4-3.html

If you are using http(s), include the username and password in your url for the server ( by editing the .git/config)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want a way that my local git can save password and use it when I am going to connect to server. Is there any such way to do this?

Comment: @user654019 - Um, that is what I am talking about.

Comment: your link does not work for me.. This webpage is not available

Answer (score 1):

The link for doing it is 
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key

Basically run the command `ssh-keygen` in the command line

save the key as ~/.ssh/id_rsa

give it an empty passphrase.

This can be used for logging in through ssh as well.

another link is [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)